# JavaFX / Bundling / MacOS Store

Tags: java, app-store

### Context

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4125530

### Question:

Does this finally mean that Java Apps will be able to be posted to the Mac Store? (Since the JRE is automatically bundled into the application), and the iOS no-JIT clause does not apply since this is for the Mac store, not the iOS store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle have packaged the [JavaFX Ensemble Sample Application](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) for Mac using pre-release JavaFX packaging tools and submitted the application to the Mac App Store. The application was accepted and you can find [Ensemble at this location in the Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ensemble/id557744983).

For JavaFX specifically, using the [JavaFX packaging tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm) which are mentioned in the ycombinator.com news item - not just yet - but potentially soon (e.g. jdk7u10 for Mac release time-frame).  For other Java projects the [Java application bundler](http://java.net/projects/appbundler) could be used (which is a seperate tool from the JavaFX packaging tools).

There are currently [a few quirks](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=labels%20=%20osx-appstore) in the javafx implementation which prevent an application packaged with the javafx packaging tools from being submittable to the Mac App Store.

How to bundle a Java App and submit it to the Mac App Store:

- [Write a Java App](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/).
- [Package the Java App for the Mac](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx).
- [Submit the Java App to the Mac App Store](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/SubmittingToMacAppStore/_index.html).

See if Apple accepts it.

Oracle have produced a guide for [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), which includes information on how to Submitting an App to the Mac App Store.

**Update**

I asked an [Oracle engineer](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=10621531) about this on Oct 8, 2012 and got the following responses.

Q. If I want to package a JavaFX application for delivery to the Mac App Store, should I use the AppBundler or the JavaFX packaging tools?

> A. JavaFX tools is way to go. At least long term (as you need to use current [beta](http://jdk7.java.net/download.html) and it might have bugs).

Q. If the JavaFX packaging tools can be used to package an application for distribution to the Mac App Store, what are the steps to do this?

> A. See materials from [Scott's talk at JavaOne](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=8224). We will publish blog on this but it may take some time.

Q. Can the JavaFX packaging tools also be used for packaging a non-JavaFX Java application for delivery to the Mac App Store?

> A. yes, see the [talkingjavadeployment blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/packaging_improvements_in_jdk_7#3).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is now YES.  Our app, Moneydance, has been submitted and approved and is now available for sale on the app store: http://infinitekind.com/moneydance-appstore.

One of our developers, Marco Dinacci, has written detailed instructions for how to do this for your app: http://intransitione.com/blog/take-java-to-app-store/